# .htaccess - catch multiple vars from query, write cookie, redir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cookies, url-rewriting

.htaccess and regular expressions is twisting my mind :)

I'm trying to catch a variable number of variables from the query string, write them in a cookie and redirect removing query string. I got it working with only one variable but sometimes I need it to catch 2 or 3. Here's the code that works with one variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(tag|aid|flu)=([a-z0-9]+)$     [NC]    # look for interesting variables in url
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?      [CO=%1:%2:foo.com:14400:/,R=301,L]  # capture url strip for vars, write cookie, redir
```

but clearly this is not going to work if the requested url is foo.com?tag=xx&aid=yyy&flu=bbb or with just two variables. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. Also it would be nice if the order of the variables didn't matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to do that:

```
# tag
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)tag=([a-z0-9]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=tag:%1:foo.com:14400:/]

# aid
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)aid=([a-z0-9]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=aid:%1:foo.com:14400:/]

# flu
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)flu=([a-z0-9]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=flu:%1:foo.com:14400:/]

# Final
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:tag|aid|flu)=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?      [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response! You don't know if the code you wrote is possible or the random order of variables in the query? :)

Comment: If that work, it's ok with random order. I never use cookie from .htaccess. I don't know if it's possible to add more than one at the same time...

Comment: hmm no, doesn't seem to work. it redirs to something like foo.com/%5bCO=aid:xxfoo.com:14400:/%5d. Do you propose that i set my cookies and redir ind php maybe ?

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache or with other browser (cache problem with 301 redirect). It is clear that there are many more possibilities in PHP...

Comment: I had forgotten `-` Try again.

Comment: No redir error now, but cookies are not written. BTW you can't outcomment with // in .htaccess I think you must use # :)

Comment: maybe my fault, 2 min!

Comment: It's my objective C day with // ;-)

Comment: hehe, things in .htaccess is just a bit weird I think. I'll now look and understand why your code works :)